# Json_table for all records including empty array

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have column with array like this `[{ amount: 5 }, { amount: 3.4} ]`
Some records are empty  `[]`

I use sum for other columns. When i try use sum with JSON_TABLE it only gives results of records where json table is not empty i think.

```
select count(1), cargo.invoice_currency_code, sum(t.amount) from cargo, JSON_TABLE(cargo.invoice_extra_charges, '$[*]' COLUMNS (amount FLOAT PATH '$.amount')) as t group by cargo.invoice_currency_code;
```

What can i do?

Comment: Show us the query you aer running please

Comment: Also tell us which version of MySQL or mariaDB you are using

Comment: I added query. So some records invoicr_extra_charges are empty and those records data are excluded from final result @RiggsFolly

Comment: I just want sum of amount inside invoice_extra_charges

Comment: Also its mysql 8

Comment: Something like: if its empty [] cast with [{ amount:0 }]

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON_TABLE() is implicitly a lateral inner join to a derived table, even if you use the comma-style join syntax.

But if the array in your JSON document is empty, it produces zero rows, so there's nothing to join against. The inner join operation eliminates the corresponding row from your `cargo` table.

But if you explicitly use outer join, you can override the implicit inner join:

```
mysql> select count(1), cargo.invoice_currency_code, sum(t.amount) 
 from cargo left outer join JSON_TABLE(cargo.invoice_extra_charges, 
   '$[*]' COLUMNS (amount FLOAT PATH '$.amount')
  ) as t on true 
 group by cargo.invoice_currency_code;

+----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| count(1) | invoice_currency_code | sum(t.amount)     |
+----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|        2 |                     1 | 8.400000095367432 |
|        1 |                     2 |              NULL |
+----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
```

The sum is returned as NULL because it's summing no values, but you can default that to zero using the [COALESCE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
mysql> select count(1), cargo.invoice_currency_code, 
  COALESCE(sum(t.amount), 0) AS sum 
 from cargo left outer join JSON_TABLE(cargo.invoice_extra_charges, 
   '$[*]' COLUMNS (amount FLOAT PATH '$.amount')
  ) as t on true 
 group by cargo.invoice_currency_code;

+----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
| count(1) | invoice_currency_code | sum               |
+----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|        2 |                     1 | 8.400000095367432 |
|        1 |                     2 |                 0 |
+----------+-----------------------+-------------------+
```